# Activiti Initiator Properties using Explorer

Tags: activiti, business-process-management

I'm using Activiti as a workflow tool for my application. Using Activiti as a backend, I'm creating a wrapper over it that interacts with it using the Activiti REST API.

To model the process, I use the Activiti Modeler which is part of Activiti Explorer.

While creating a process I specify the `activiti:initiator` to be `employeeName` in the start event, which I can then use in any other task's documentation as `${employeeName}`

But the variable `employeeName` stores the ID of the user. If in any other user task's documentation, I need to use the first and last name properties of employeeName, how would I do that?

I've already tried snippets from elsewhere saying to use `${employeeName.properties.firstName}` to no avail. It gives an error when the process starts.

PS: since it is a web application, only REST API is used with HTML / PHP, no java code is written. So probably a suggestion how to do it in Activiti Explorer or Modeler itself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing the point of the question, but there is a REST API that will return the user's details. From memory it is GET /service/identity/users/{userId}

Obviously if you are using a different Rest Context then "service" will be your actual context.

Hope this helps.

Greg - BP3

Comment: I am using identity/users to get that information in my wrapper. But as I mentioned, I need to reference it in the documentation of another user task. So that the task's documentation reads proper firstname and lastname instead on userId.